# Can we say that the following Power series has eventually non-decreasing coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, fourier-analysis

A power series
$$ \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n $$ is said to have a eventually non-decreasing coefficients if there exists $$k \in \mathbb{N} $$ such  that $$ a_n \leq a_{n+1}, \forall n \geq k .$$

We consider the following obvious case to understand our problem :
Power series given by :
$$ \frac{1}{(1-t)} = 1+t+t^2+...+t^n+....$$
has coefficients eventually constant, in particular they are eventually non-decreasing.

`Can we give a proof that the following Power series has eventually non-decreasing coefficients ?`
$$ \frac{1}{1-(t^2(t^r+1))} = 1 + t^2(t^r+1) + (t^2(t^r+1))^2 + (t^2(t^r+1))^3 + ... +(t^2(t^r+1))^n + ....$$

where r $\in$ odd natural number.

Comment: What have you tried to solve tjhis problem? Alternatively, can you provide context of where this problem arises?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point might be to work it out for small $r$, like $r=1$.

Comment: "The following power series" is not a power series, i.e., is not expressed in the form $\sum_n a_nt^n$; your first task is to make it so.

Comment: note that for $r$ even $a_{2n+1}=0$ so the result is definitely not true; for $r$ odd it reduces to studying $\sum_c {\frac{n-cr}{2} \choose r}$ where $cr \le n, 2 |n-cr$  and see if this increases for large $n$